# Exit Sub on Cancel or X on Input box

Tags: excel, vba

I'm attempting to add an option that if the X or cancel button are clickied on the input box, then it will exit the sub. However it looks like i'm not adding this in the correct order and instead exit's the sub regardless. Can anyone attempt and execute this correctly?

```
Sub openurl()

Dim EdgeLocation As String
Dim MyURL As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim inputValue As Variant ' n

range("A1").Select

lastRow = Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

Set ws1 = Sheets("Page1_1")

EdgeLocation = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe" 'Location of Edge.exe in your PC

For i = 1 To lastRow

    ' Copy the adjacent value in column CM
    Dim valueToCopy As String
    valueToCopy = ActiveSheet.range("CL" & i).Value
    ActiveSheet.range("CL" & i).Copy

   '  ActiveSheet.range("CL" & i).EntireRow.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)

MyURL = ws1.Cells(i, 1)
    Shell (EdgeLocation & " -url -newtab " & MyURL)
    
    
       If ActiveSheet.range("CN" & i) = InputBox("Enter Y or N for POD", "InputBox Example") = vbOK Then

        
            range("CN1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "POD"
    
       Else
       
       'MsgBox "You have cancelled the process..."
       Exit Sub
       End If

Next i


End Sub
```

Comment: `InputBox` returns a blank `String` if you cancel it. So get the return value of the `InputBox` first, before you compare it to the Range (or use similar logic) so you can `Exit Sub` if it's a zero length `String`. (and `vbOK` is not part of an `InputBox`, that's a `MsgBox`.)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a message box to cancel as it was easier for me because my inputbox has a string based answer.

```
     ' Msg box to continue or quit
         If MsgBox("Continue to the next URL?", vbOKCancel + vbQuestion) = vbOK Then

Else
'Statements to show before Exit the Process
'MsgBox "You have skipped the Process"

Exit Sub
End If
```